# Pass parameter in Hop Run

Tags: pentaho, apache-hop

can you help me pass a parameter of a Workflow in Apache Hop Run?

I did as instructed on the site and tried other ways but the message below always appears

```
.\hop-run.bat -j ROTINA_SUPERA -r local -e PROD_ROTINA_SUPERA -f "C:\Apache Hop\Pipelines\ROTINA_SUPERA\ATUALIZACAO_SUPERA.hwf" -p anomes=2023-02
```

[image]

Obs.: In Hop gui it works normally passing the value "2023-02" for the parameter "anomes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work this way:

```
.\hop-run.bat -j ROTINA_SUPERA -r local -e PROD_ROTINA_SUPERA -f "C:\Apache Hop\Pipelines\ROTINA_SUPERA\ATUALIZACAO_SUPERA.hwf" -p=\"anomes=2023-02\"
```